# Vue.js vue-router: How to go back without a page reload?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

Here is the crux of the problem:

[image]

Things to note:

- The query is updated in vuex on input/search
- After a product click, a user is moved using `user.push('/product/'+ asin)`
- When moving back, I tried both `router.push('/')` as well as `router.go(-1)`

Every time the user returns, the value of query is lost and the list of results is reloaded.

Is there an easy off the shelf recipe so that this doesn't happen? Thank you.

Additional info: As you can see, after the back button is pressed, momentarily the list of fetched products is displayed exactly as before; then for some reason the query is emptied (and results are cleared)

Comment: If the query's stored in vuex state then how does it get lost? Without any code it's very hard to help you. What you described has to work in words. You store the query somewhere globally, then every time component gets mounted you just use the value.

Comment: You can also try to use `keep-alive` for the router-view

Comment: @oniondomes I've removed every functionality responsible for clearing the items... Once the back button is hit, it appears that the entire page is refreshed. I've tried `replace` and `push`... How could I monitor at which point does query become empty? Quite puzzling

Comment: As was previously said without code it's hard to try to help. I think maybe I understand what is going on here and why, what you need to do in / is accommodate for the fact that the query can already exist as @oniondomes said you should store it globally and reference this, sorta like a session value. When you push / it will reinitialize the state I guess but within that you've disregarded that there can be a global query value to start off with?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder This may be helpful: Chrome's back button works EXACTLY as intended. The problem (after looking at the app through Vuex Inspect Chrome tool) appears to be with `router.push` / `router.go` / `router.replace`. Is there another method?

Comment: @dsp_099 what you got in the animation is expected behaviour. On route change "list" component gets mounted once again, which probably triggers a request for a fresh item list. From what you have written so far it seems that you store or mutate data in vuex incorrect somehow. Hard to tell what exactly went wrong as nothing actually refers at how you've done it in your question.

Comment: Yup, what happens to the input value? Is it not a value in your vuex store?

Comment: The list (products) and the input (query) are both computed properties/getters. Their value is both overwritten as `[]` and `''` as those are defaults in the Vuex store.

Comment: It appears that `<router-link to="/"></router-link>` works exactly as expected. Still curious what the issue is

Comment: Might help to see your route configuration or maybe a simple mockup application which highlights the issue. What you have said rings a bell for me but I can't remember why or how it was resolved. Please post an answer when you have more info/understanding on the matter :)

Comment: @Craig van Tonder I'm on a crunch with other stuff but I'll definitely do that when I can slice it all up and down - there is a LOT of stuff to remove and just posting a working example would take some time.

Comment: Yup I can understand the position no worries. In all honesty, that's how I solve most of issues that i've had in the past though. Whilst breaking things down and trying to simplify them to better explain my question I often end up finding the answer within that. Looking forward to the response and information though, will hold you to that !